# UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY error with Azure storage explorer on MacOS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I am using Azure storage explorer on Mac OS to connect to ADLS using Azure AD. I am able to access the containers when I just login into my Mac, but if Mac goes on sleep after that if I try to access the containers I get the error as `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY`. Again if I restart the Macbook it works fine.
So, is there anything I can do to overcome this issue, like clearing any temp folder or clearing any files to make it work? Any help is appreciated.
*I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the certificate issue, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C1804#error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-and-similar-errors) to troubleshoot.

Or you can directly open the storage explorer in the command line with the `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag, then it will ignore the certificate error.